# C# Console Application - cmd.exe hangs

Tags: c#, windows-8, cmd, console-application, visual-studio-2013

I am having issues with running a simple C# Console Application in Visual Studio 2013.

Details of my problem: I was running Console Applications successfully with the default "Press any key to continue" displaying cleanly at the end. Suddenly it started behaving differently with the following symptoms:

- A new command window (cmd.exe) opening alongside my Console Application (this wasn't happening in the past)
- My Console Application closing abruptly without the default clean "Press any key" message
- cmd.exe hangs and I am unable to close it, even through the Task Manager -> End Process

My System Properties:

- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- Windows 8, x64

This is my Console Application code just to show that it isn't a problem in my code:

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegularTest();      
        }
        private static void RegularTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the Regular Test. It works!");
        }
}
```

Comment: This application WILL close as soon as it executes the writeline.  There is nothing to stop it.  Add `Console.Read()` to accept a single character to continue.  The "Press any key" message comes from the dos `Pause` command.  Perhaps you were using that previously, maybe in a batchfile?

Comment: Actually I vaguely remember seeing this, or something very much like this, before as a result of a Visual Studio error which was quickly hotfixed. Pretty sure that was Visual Studio 2010 though, and I'll be darned if I can find any info about what I'm remembering on Google :( Sorry, I know that's not very helpful...

Comment: It would also be a lot more helpful if you showed code that *IS* a problem.  This executes without error

Comment: Ah hah, here it is. It was VS2008. This may not be related to your issue (probably isn't) but just in case. Sorry I can't offer more help. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6d4a4f5-7002-401a-90e1-6174d7f9e3ca/vs-2008-debugging-console-window-will-not-close-when-debugging-stopped?forum=vsdebug

Comment: @paqogomez if you run the console app using Ctrl-F5 then it automatically pauses at the end (or should).

Comment: This behaviour depends on Debug and Release selection while starting your app.

Answer (score 3):

We had the exact same problem here during several weeks !
And we finally found a solution !

In our case, it was the **anti-virus Avast** which was corrupting the generated `.exe` !

The solution was to simply disable all agents while generating the release !

If you use another anti-virus, try to disable it.

Comment: Yes. This case occured on my private computer where I have avast. ConsoleApplication persists in running applications and it is really hard to kill it. Avast corrupting .exe without ANY NOTIFICATION and suspend/block forever. :/

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be a very new issue. I have not seen it act this way until today. I guess I'm going to use another antivirus for a while.